# Spring Integration XSD Validation FIlter

Tags: spring-integration

Please let me know if there is a way to override the default soap fault thrown by spring integration XSD validator. By default the fault generated is a client fault, But I want to change it to a custom fault code. Is AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver.getFaultDefinition() the right place to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Integration XSD Validator doesn't throw any Fault exceptions.

The Fault is a specific of the SOAP protocol and Spring WS wraps anyway service downstream Exception to the SOAP Fault using default strategy in face of:

```
org.springframework.ws.server.EndpointExceptionResolver=org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver,\
  org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.SoapFaultAnnotationExceptionResolver
```

That is only way to customize it: implement your own `EndpointExceptionResolver` with desired logic.

Yes, perhaps `AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver.getFaultDefinition()` is for your case.

We need to know more context on the matter.

From other side looks like we have talked with you about similar issue in other your questions...